# Notepad++ replace last symbol in search regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got the syntax:

```
 "DI000001-DM-BEL-THONL-D1"
```

that needs to be split up into

```
"DI000001","DM-BEL-THONL-D1"
```

It can be only be found using this regex:

```
DI[0-9]{5,6}-
```

But it's the last - that needs to be replaced with ","

How do you cut out a symbol in a backreference?

Comment: Untested: `(DI[0-9]{5,6})-`, replace with "$1,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for this

```
(DI\d{5,6})-
```

And replace with

```
$1","
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "cut out a symbol in a backreference", but you can use a capturing group over the pattern that matches the text you need to keep (and use a backreference to it in the replacement pattern - see [Niitaku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066094/3832970)) or discard a part of the text matched so far in a current iteration using `\K` operator:

```
DI[0-9]{5,6}\K-
            ^^
```

Replace with `","`.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Learnt something new. `\K` for memory loss. Is there in Python's re module?

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer but I've marked Niitaku's as this did not work for me (maybe a version/plugin difference?)

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: Nope, windows (8.1)

Comment: Then I have no clue why it did not work. Anyway, I also think that a capturing group/backreference is the best approach, `\K` is a PCRE/Boost-only construct. Handy but not so portable.

Comment: After testing it in a different file it does work, my apologies